# Constructor initialization behavior

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Not an expert so when I noticed the following behavior I was not clear why this is the case - would appreciate someone explaining.

```
class Example 
{
   public: 
   Example() {}
};

int main()
{
  Example ex (Example()); 
  cout << typeid(ex).name() << endl;    
}
```

results to:

> class Example __cdecl(class Example (__cdecl*)(void))

A non-default constructor initializes an instance of "class Example" as expected. Of course, assignment initialization also works as expected.

```
Example ex2 = Example();
```

> class Example

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 3):

This

```
Example ex (Example());
```

is a function declaration with name `ex` that has return type `Example` and a parameter of type `Example()` where `Example()` is in turn a function type that has return type Example and no parameters..

The same declaration can be rewritten like

```
Example ex (Example ( * )());
```

because functions passed as parameters are implicitly converted to pointers to functions.

In this case if you want to call the copy constructor you have to supply an expression as an argument

```
Example ex ( ( Example() ) );
```

or

```
Example ex ( { Example() } );
```

As for this declaration

```
Example ex2 = Example();
```

then there is used an initializer that is an expression that represents itself a call of the default constructor.

Consider this confusing example for a laugh

```
#include <iostream>

class Example 
{
   public: 
   Example() {}
};

Example ex() { return Example(); }

int main()
{
    Example ex( Example() );

    ex( ::ex );
}

Example ex( Example ( ex() ) )
{
    std::cout << "Example ex( Example ( ex() ) ) is called" << std::endl;

    return ex();
}
```

Comment: Indeed figured out after deeper reading and is defined in the standard.  .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse